# How to use functions to make a goto line function python

Tags: python

On other answers for the goto line function in python have said that it isn't possible, but I was wondering if it was possible to define a function that allowed you to make labels and goto's. This is just for proof of concept, so people can see if a goto line/label command is possible in python.
How do you make a goto line/label function in python(like a goto function, not a loop)?

Comment: If you've already seen the answer, why are you asking again?

Comment: There is a [`goto` module](http://entrian.com/goto/). I don't know whether it works, though. Also, [you should avoid `goto` alltogether](https://www.xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: It's possible to do. `pdb` is able to do it somehow with the jump command.

Comment: I'm asking because it has to be possible in a way, just for a proof of concept.

Comment: @user3875728 Do you want to jump to labels or to line numbers? I bet the former could be hacked together somehow using generators as coroutines...

Comment: @hlt That library does some really ugly stuff, it basically re-parses your file and then calls `eval` on specific line numbers. Hm, I wonder if there's a nicer way...

Answer (score 0):

I have a function decorator that adds goto to a function: https://github.com/cdjc/goto
It is for python 3 and modifies the bytecode of the function.

So yes. It is possible.

There is an older version for python 2 (but it has some bugs)